# FileUpload showbuttons="false" Primefaces keep showing buttons

Tags: java, button, file-upload, primefaces

I'm working with the FileUpload component,  I set the property showButtons="false" , but the buttons are still shown when the file is being uploadded. :(

```
<p:fileUpload  showButtons="false" label="#{messages['upload.xls']}" 
        fileUploadListener="#{oaBean.handleFileUpload}"
auto="true"/>
```

Why this is not working? Or I am just misunderstanding the behaivor of the property? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest walkaround I found : Hiding them via CSS .

```
    .start
{
    display:none;
}

.cancel
{
    display:none;   
}
```

I still don't know why the property isn't working as it should, but this at least fix my issue.